# The conditional probability when some random variables are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For $n \geq 1$,  let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables each with a value equals $1$ or $0$ with probability $p$ and $q$, respectively.

If $N = \inf \{n \geq 0, Z_{n+1} = 1 \}$ such that $Z_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ is a sequence of random variables defined exactly as the first sequence above "sequence of $X_i$" *and independent of it.*

Show that: $1.~~ p(\cap_{i=1}^n  (X_i=x_i) /N=n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(X_i=x_i /N=n).$

$2.~~ \forall i \in[1,n],~~p(X_i = 1/ N=n) = p(X_i=1 /X_iY_i=0) = \frac{p(1-q)}{1-pq}.$

$\Longrightarrow$ I tried with the first part as

\begin{eqnarray}
p(\cap_{i=1}^n  (X_i=x_i) /N=n) &=& p((X_1=x_1 \cap X_2=x_2 \dots \cap X_n=x_n)/N=n)\\
&=& \frac{p((X_1=x_1 \cap X_2=x_2 \dots \cap X_n=x_n) \cap N=n)}{p(N=n)}\\
\text{after that I should say }\\
&=& p((X_1=x_1) /N=n) p((X_2=x_2) /N=n) \dots p((X_n=x_n) /N=n)\\
&=&  \prod_{i=1}^n p(X_i=x_i /N=n)
\end{eqnarray}

But I don't know how to get this. I know that the sequence is independent but I don't see how I can use this property to arrive to the last two lines.

$\Longrightarrow$ For the second part, we know

$N \sim Geometric(pq)$, $Z_n \sim \text{Binomial}(n,pq)$ and $p(X_i =1)=p$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
p(X_i = 1/ N=n) &=& \frac{p(X_i=1 \cap N=n)}{p(N=n)}\\
&=& \vdots
\end{eqnarray}

and I don't know also how to continue from here. I really appreciate any help or hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one:

Notice first that $$N=n \iff (X_1 =0\cup Y_1=0)\cap(X_2 =0\cup Y_2=0) \cdots \cap(X_{n+1} =1\cap Y_{n+1}=1) $$

Let's abuse notation to abbreviate $p(x_i) = P(X_i = x_i)$ , $p(n)=P(N=n)$, etc. Then

$$p(x_i \mid  n)=\frac{p(n\mid  x_i) p(x_i)}{p(n)} \tag1$$

But, for $1\le i\le  n$:

$$
\begin{align}
p(n)&=(1-p^2)^n p^2 = q^{n}(1+p)^{n} p^2 \tag 2 \\
p(n\mid x_i)&=(1-p^2)^{n-1} p^2 q^{x_i}  \tag 3 \\
p(x_i)&= p^{x_i} q^{1-x_i} = q \, (p/q)^{x_i} \tag 4
\end{align}
$$

Hence

$$p(x_i\mid n)=\frac{q^{x_i} q \, (p/q)^{x_i}}{1-p^2}=p^{x_i} (1+p)^{-1}
\tag 5$$
and
$$\prod p(x_i \mid  n) = p^{w_x} (1+p)^{-n} \tag 6$$
where $w_x=\sum x_i$ is the weight of the bistring ${\bf x}=(x_1 \cdots x_n)$

Now, we compute the joint prob:

$$p({\bf x}\mid  n)=\frac{p(n\mid  {\bf x}) p({\bf x})}{p(n)}$$

with

$$p({\bf x})=p^{w_x} \, q^{n-w_x} \tag 7$$

$$p(n\mid  {\bf x})=q^{w_x } p^2 \tag 8$$

So

$$p({\bf x}\mid  n) = \frac{p^{w_x} q^n p^2 }{q^{n}(1+p)^{n} p^2}=p^{w_x} (1+p)^{-n} \tag 9$$

which coincides with $(6)$.

For the second part, I get, from $(5)$

$$p(X_i=1 \mid  n) = \frac{p}{1+p}=\frac{pq}{1-p^2}$$

which does not coincide with your value. It coincides, however with

$$ P(X_i=1 \mid X_i Y_i=0) = \frac{ P(X_i Y_i=0\mid  X_i=1 ) P(X_i=1)}{P(X_i Y_i=0)}=\frac{q \, p}{1-p^2} $$

Care to check that?

Comment: First of all thank. I jut verified from the second part which you found it equal to $\frac{pq}{1-p^2}$ while it is in the question equals $\frac{p^2}{1-pq}$ so there is something wrong

Comment: @adam I mentioned that that result of mine does not agree with the question. That's why I asked the OP to recheck. My value seems right, unless I misunderstood something. Furthermore, my result can be checked to agree with the elementary computation of $P(X_i=1 |X_i Y_i=0)$

Comment: Could you please clarify how did you find that $p(X_iY_i = 0) = 1-p^2$ and $p(X_iY_i =0/X_i=1) = q$?

Comment: The product $X_iY_i$ is not zero only when both are 1. That is $p(X_iY_i = 0) =1- P(X_i=1 \cap Y_i =1)$

Comment: Much clear. I would be very grateful if you just clarify how you got equations $3$ and $4$.

Comment: Eq $(4)$ is just a compact (and standard) way of writing the single probabilities (check that it gives the right values for $x_i=0$ and $x_i=1$).
Eq $(3)$ is a little more complex, but, again, is a compact way of writing the two conditional probabilities:  $p(n\mid x_i=0)=(1-p^2)^{n-1} p^2 $ and :  $p(n\mid x_i=1)=(1-p^2)^{n-1} p^2 q $

Answer (score 1):

Nice question! I enjoyed working out the solution. It's certainly not immediately obvious, by any stretch!

---

Suppose that $N = n$. This means that $Z_m = 0$ for all $1 \le m \le n$ and also $Z_{n+1} = 1$. (Note that $Z_1, Z_2, ...$ changes by $0$ or $1$ in a single step.) From this we deduce that $X_m Y_m = 0$ for all $1 \le m \le n$ and $X_{n+1} = 1 = Y_{n+1}$.
Note the symmetry regarding $X_i Y_i$ over $i \in [1,n]$, and recall the independence. This allows you to deduce **Q2**.

For **Q1**, for ease of presentation, let's consider $n = 2$. The general case follows (extremely) similarly.
We have
$$ a := \Pr( X_1 = x_1, \: X_2 = x_2; \: N = n ) = \Pr( X_1 = x_1, \: Y_1 = \bar x_1; X_2 = x_2, \: Y_2 = \bar y_2; X_3 = 1, \: Y_3 = 1 ), $$
where $\bar x := 1 - x$ (the 'complement' in $\{0,1\}$).
I am assuming that the $Y$-sequence is independent of the $X$-sequence (otherwise I highly doubt it's true). So this just becomes
$$ a = \Pr(X_1 = x_1) \Pr(Y_1 = \bar x_1) \Pr(Y_2 = x_2) \Pr(Y_2 = \bar x_2) \Pr(X_3 = 1) \Pr(Y_3 = 1).$$
But since we always have pairs, $(x_1, \bar x_1) = (x_1, 1 - x_1)$ and $(x_2, \bar x_2) = (x_2, 1 - x_2)$, we always have
$$ a = (pq)^2 \cdot p^2. $$
In general, we would have
$$ \Pr( \cap_1^n \{X_i = x_1\}, \: N = n ) = (pq)^n \cdot p^2. $$

Ok, so we've found actually exactly what one side is.
We can do in essence the same calculation for $\Pr(N = n)$.
Indeed,
$$ \Pr(N = n \mid \cap_1^n \{X_i = x_i\}) = \Pr(\cap_1^n \{Y_i = \bar x_i\}; \: X_{n+1} = 1, \: Y_{n+1} = 1).$$

---

Can you try to finish from here? I don't want to give away the *entire* question! :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and yes both sequences are independent with each other. For part $2$, I understand the first equality but mathematically for the second equality, I don't see how to get the result especially that $X_i$ and $X_iY_i$ are independent so $p(X_i=1 /X_iY_i =0) = p(X_i=1) = p$.

For part $1$, there is no way to prove the equality directly using the relation between $X$ , $Y$ and the independence? Is proving that both side giving the same result is the only method "easier"?

Comment: @adam, I'm not sure, there is possibly some way of going directly for Q1. This just seemed the most natural way to me. Note that I *did not* use anything about the distribution of $N$. You can probably use the fact that
$$ \textstyle \{N = n\} = \bigl( \{ X_{n+1} = 1 \} \cap \{ Y_{n+1} = 1 \} \bigr) \cap \bigcap_1^n \bigl( \{ X_i = 0 \} \cup \{ Y_i = 0 \} \bigr) $$
to put the $N = n$ in terms of $(X,Y)$ then use independence in some way.

Comment: For Q2, let's think about what $\Pr(X_1 = 1 \mid X_1Y_1 = 0)$ means. It means that *at least* one of $X_1$ or $Y_1$ is $0$, but you don't know which one. Use Bayes's theorem and the fact that $A \cap (B \cup C \cup D) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \cap (A \cap D)$ with $A := \{X_1 = 1\}$ and $B$, $C$ and $D$ the *three* choices of $(X_1, Y_1)$ which satisfy $X_1 Y_1 = 0$. These are then disjoint events, so the probabilities sum.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation but I think this will not give the result for $Q_2$, as you see
\begin{eqnarray}
p(X_k= 1/ X_kY_k = 0) &=& \frac{p(X_k= 1 \cap \{(X_k= 1,Y_k= 0) \cup (X_k= 0,Y_k=1) \cup (X_k= 0,Y_k= 0) \})}{p(X_kY_k = 0)} \\
&=& \frac{  p(\{X_k= 1 \cap X_k= 1,Y_k= 0 \} \cup \{X_k= 1 \cap X_k= 0,Y_k=1\} \cup \{X_k= 1 \cap X_k= 0,Y_k= 0\} }{p(X_kY_k = 0)} \\
&=& \frac{  p(X_k= 1 \cap X_k= 1,Y_k= 0 ) + 0+0}{p(X_kY_k = 0)} \\
\end{eqnarray}

since $p(X_k= 1 \cap X_k= 0,Y_k=1) =0$ and $p(X_k= 1 \cap X_k= 0,Y_k= 0) =0$ so for sure there is something missing

Comment: I think I unnecessarily complicated things. We have
\begin{align}
\Pr(X_1 = 1 \mid X_1 Y_1 = 0) &= \Pr(X_1 = 1, \: X_1Y_1 = 0)/\Pr(X_1Y_1 = 0) \\&= \Pr(X_1 = 1, \: Y_1 = 0) / \bigl(1 - \Pr(X_1 = 1, \: Y_1 = 1)\bigr) = pq/(1-p^2). \end{align}
The key is to use the symmetry to reduce to $\Pr(X_1 = 1 \mid N = n) = \Pr(X_1 = 1 \mid X_1Y_1 = 0)$.

Comment: I already found this result and it is not equal to the result of the question $= \frac{p^2}{1-pq}$

Comment: Then I can state pretty definitively that the question is wrong :) -- I notice that the other answerer also got, via a different argument, the same answer as I did

Comment: If your question has been answered, then it is best if you pick the answer which helped you the most and mark it as accepted. Also, it's polite to upvote an answer if you found it useful. It seems that you have found both useful, but only my answer has an upvote. Don't forget to upvote both :)